# How to make a query with multiple sums in a single row without subqueries?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a query which returns four different sums based on a column, but don't know how to do it without subqueries.

What I need to do is basically this: I have two tables, "caixa" and "movimentacao". The table "movimentacao" has a field "type", which ranges from 0 to 3, and a field "value", and need a query which returns the sum of value from each type of "movimentacao" belonging to a "caixa", but in a single row, so grouping by the type won't work.

So far my solution is:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT SUM(value) FROM movimentacao where id_caixa = x.id_caixa and type = 0)
    (SELECT SUM(value) FROM movimentacao where id_caixa = x.id_caixa and type = 1)
    (SELECT SUM(value) FROM movimentacao where id_caixa = x.id_caixa and type = 2)
    (SELECT SUM(value) FROM movimentacao where id_caixa = x.id_caixa and type = 3)
FROM caixa x
```

Is there a way to do this without these four subqueries, using joins instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM( CASE WHEN m.type = 0 THEN x.value END ) as type_0,
       SUM( CASE WHEN m.type = 1 THEN x.value  END ) as type_1,
       SUM( CASE WHEN m.type = 2 THEN x.value  END ) as type_2,
       SUM( CASE WHEN m.type = 3 THEN x.value  END ) as type_3
FROM caixa x JOIN
     movimentacao m
     ON x.id_caixa = m.id_caixa;
```

Comment: How would this sum the `value` column?

Comment: @mypetlion . . . It does now.

Comment: Would that work if I were using two tables that depended on `caixa` instead of just one, each with its own `type` field?

Comment: @ayrton . . . That depends.  If you have another question, you should ask it as a *new* question, with appropriate sample data and desired results.